# Can I write comments inside a "normal" diff/patch file?

Tags: diff, patch

I used `diff` to produce a patch file. `diff old.txt new.txt`:

```
1c1
< Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
---
> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

The output is in the default "normal diff" format.

Can I write comments in this patch file? If so, will the patch file be reasonably portable?

Comment: BTW at least in my experience the traditional diff format is rarely used. Afaict it suffers from the problem of providing no context, so if the file to patch is not identical to the file that was used to generate the patch, mis-application becomes more likely. Most diff files nowadays are distributed in the "unified" format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

patch ignores lines that don't look like diff-output until it finds a chunk which matches that syntax.  This is reasonably portable: existing implementations do this.  The patches which I construct (e.g., using [`diff-patch`](https://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:diff-patch)) for ncurses and xterm all have a preamble giving the ***[diffstat](https://invisible-island.net/diffstat/diffstat.html)***, prefixing the lines with "#" to make this unambiguous, e.g., [quoting](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2020-03/msg00017.html) one:

```
# ncurses 6.2 - patch 20200301 - Thomas E. Dickey
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Ncurses 6.2 is at
#       ftp.gnu.org:/pub/gnu
#
# Patches for ncurses 6.2 can be found at
#       ftp://ftp.invisible-island.net/ncurses/6.2
#       http://invisible-mirror.net/archives/ncurses/6.2 
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ftp://ftp.invisible-island.net/ncurses/6.2/ncurses-6.2-20200301.patch.gz
# patch by Thomas E. Dickey <dickey@invisible-island.net>
# created  Mon Mar  2 23:18:56 UTC 2020
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# NEWS                             |    8 +++++++-
# VERSION                          |    2 +-
# dist.mk                          |    4 ++--
# ncurses/base/lib_bkgd.c          |   12 +++++++++++-
# package/debian-mingw/changelog   |    4 ++--
# package/debian-mingw64/changelog |    4 ++--
# package/debian/changelog         |    4 ++--
# package/mingw-ncurses.nsi        |    4 ++--
# package/mingw-ncurses.spec       |    2 +-
# package/ncurses.spec             |    2 +-
# package/ncursest.spec            |    2 +-
# 11 files changed, 32 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index: NEWS
Prereq:  1.3455 
--- ncurses-6.2-20200229+/NEWS  2020-02-29 23:15:52.000000000 +0000
+++ ncurses-6.2-20200301/NEWS   2020-03-02 01:55:08.000000000 +0000
@@ -26,7 +26,7 @@
 -- sale, use or other dealings in this Software without prior written        --
 -- authorization.                                                            --
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

On the other hand, someone *could* construct a new patch program which gives an error in this case.  Given the thirty-year history of this program, the lack of portability would reflect on the "new" program rather than how it is currently used.

Comment: The "junk preamble" works ONLY at the beginning of the file. Otherwise, a "patch" is everything between the "`---`" lines. No place for comments.

Comment: OP didn't specify.  However, patch works on one file at a time, with one or more chunks (whose length is well-defined).  The same script adds an `Index` line between files, using that well-defined sense, and comments could be inserted in the same way.  (patch would be confused by inserting text **between** chunks, but your comment isn't making that distinction).

Answer (score -1):

No. Not if you're planning to feed the `diff` to a program, e.g. `patch`.

Can you think of a comment syntax that could NEVER be part of a `diff`/`patch` flow? I cannot.

Changes should be documented elsewhere.